Creating tables dynamically
I want to create a table like so:

Such that the number of Q1, Q2, Q3 like columns can be passed as an argument.The following however:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{pgffor}    


\newcommand{\tabledyn}[1]{%
\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{1.5cm}p{1cm}*{#1}{p{1cm}}p{1cm}p{1.5cm}}[hvlines]
    \Block{2-1}{Col A}     
    & \Block{2-1}{Col B} 
    & \foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {Q\i & } \relax % Dynamically generate Q columns
    \Block{2-1}{Col Y}  & \Block{2-1}{Col Z} \\
\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\tabledyn{3}

\end{document}

does not display the Q1, Q2, Q3 and skips out on 'Col Y':

nicematrix says:
The preamble of your environment {NiceTabular}

(nicematrix)                announces 7 columns but you use only 5.
(nicematrix)                You can go on but the columns you did not used
(nicematrix)                won't be created.

Would appreciate some help.

\foreach of pgffor creates a TeX group which interferes with the & of the tabular.
I suggest to use \int_step_inline:nn for the loop. In order to use that command of the L3 programming layer, you have to activate the corresponding syntax with \ExplSyntaxOn (and switch off with \ExplSyntaxOff).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\tabledyn}[1]{%
\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{w{c}{1.5cm}w{c}{1cm}*{#1}{w{c}{1cm}}w{c}{1cm}w{c}{1.5cm}}[hvlines]
    \Block{2-1}{Col A}     
    & \Block{2-1}{Col B} 
    & \int_step_inline:nn { #1 } { Q##1 & } 
    \Block{2-1}{Col Y}  & \Block{2-1}{Col Z} \\
\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tabledyn{3}

\end{document}



You can't use \foreach to span columns.
I'd define a general purpose \stepdo command, that we can apply in the specific case. The last argument is a template where the current value in the loop is denoted by #1 (but we need ##1 if inside a definition, as usual).
Here the template is Q#1 &, so the final result with three columns would be Q1 & Q2 & Q3 &
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\stepdo}{O{1}mm}
 {% #1 = start (default 1), #2 = end, #3 = template
  \cs_gset:Nn \__walser_stepdo:n {#3}
  \int_step_function:nnN {#1} {#2} \__walser_stepdo:n
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\tabledyn}[1]{%
  \begin{center}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{w{c}{1.5cm}w{c}{1cm}*{#1}{w{c}{1cm}}w{c}{1cm}w{c}{1.5cm}}[hvlines]
    \Block{2-1}{Col A}     
    & \Block{2-1}{Col B} 
    & \stepdo{#1}{Q##1 &} % Dynamically generate Q columns
    \Block{2-1}{Col Y}  & \Block{2-1}{Col Z} \\
    \\
  \end{NiceTabular}
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\tabledyn{3}
\bigskip

\tabledyn{2}

\end{document}

Note w{c}{<dimen>} instead of p{<dimen>}. You'd need >{\centering}p{1cm} otherwise, but for cells that don't have text to be broken across lines, the w column type is better.

